# Hibernate Group by Entity issue

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a group by query like

```
Select r.release.protected_, r.release.releaseType, r.version  FROM 
ReleaseCategory r where r.release.lifecycleStatus = :lifecycleStatus and 
r.release.releaseType is not null 
group by r.release.protected_, r.release.releaseType, r.version`
```

Getting the exception is

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column
>   "releasetyp3_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an
>   aggregate function   Position: 123

Hibernate output query is

```
select release1_.PROTECTED as col_0_0_, 
    release1_.RELEASE_TYPE_ID as col_1_0_, 
    releasecat0_.VERSION_ID as col_2_0_, 
    releasetyp3_.ID as ID1_11_0_, 
    version4_.ID as ID1_16_1_, 
    releasetyp3_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT2_11_0_, 
    releasetyp3_.NAME as NAME3_11_0_, 
    version4_.EDITION_ID as EDITION_3_16_1_, 
    version4_.PLATFORM_ID as PLATFORM4_16_1_, 
    version4_.VERSION_NAME as VERSION_2_16_1_ 
from schema1.RELEASE_CATEGORY releasecat0_ cross join schema1.RELEASE release1_ 
    inner join schema1.RELEASE_TYPE releasetyp3_ on release1_.RELEASE_TYPE_ID=releasetyp3_.ID 
    inner join schema1.VERSION version4_ on releasecat0_.VERSION_ID=version4_.ID 
where releasecat0_.RELEASE_ID=release1_.id 
    and release1_.LIFECYCLE_STATUS=? 
    and (release1_.RELEASE_TYPE_ID is not null) 
group by release1_.PROTECTED , release1_.RELEASE_TYPE_ID , releasecat0_.VERSION_ID
```

Query Formation:

```
 StringBuffer sqlString = new StringBuffer();
        sqlString.append("Select r.release.protected_, r.release.releaseType, r.version  ");
        sqlString.append(" FROM ReleaseCategory r where r.release.lifecycleStatus = :lifecycleStatus ");
        sqlString.append(" and r.release.releaseType is not null ");
        sqlString.append(" group by r.release.protected_, r.release.releaseType, r.version ");

        TypedQuery<Object[]> query = entityManager.createQuery( sqlString.toString(),Object[].class );
        em.flush();
        List<Object[]> results = null;
        query.setParameter("lifecyleStatus", "active");
        results = query.getResultList();
```

I am using Postgresql 9.5.x.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="RELEASE_CATEGORY")
public class ReleaseCategory implements Serializable  {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8745765537011255150L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`enter code here`
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private long id;


    @JoinColumn(name="RELEASE_ID", nullable=false)
    private Release release;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PLATFORM_ID", nullable=false)
    private Platform platform;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="EDITION_ID", nullable=false)
    private Edition edition;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="VERSION_ID", nullable=false)
    private Version version;

    public ReleaseCategory() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Release getRelease() {
        return this.Release;
    }

    public void setRelease(Release release) {
        this.release = release;
    }

    public Platform getPlatform() {
        return platform;
    }

    public void setPlatform(Platform platform) {
        this.platform = platform;
    }

    public Edition getEdition() {
        return edition;
    }

    public void setEdition(Edition edition) {
        this.edition = edition;
    }

    public Version getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Version version) {
        this.version = version;
    }   

}

    import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Table(name="RELEASE")
public class Release implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3030747033983038600L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="LIFECYCLE_STATUS", nullable=false, length=255)
    private String lifecycleStatus;

    @Column(name="OPERATING_SYSTEM", nullable=false, length=255)
    private String operatingSystem;

    @Column(name="PROTECTED", nullable=false, length=5)
    private String protected_;

    @Column(name="RELEASE_DATE", nullable=false)
    private Timestamp releaseDate;

    @Column(name="RELEASE_NAME", unique=true, nullable=false, length=255)
    private String releaseName;

    @Column(name="SHORT_DESCRIPTION", nullable=false, length=255)
    private String shortDescription;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to pFile
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="release", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,
                                                                        CascadeType.REMOVE, 
                                                                        CascadeType.REFRESH,
                                                                        CascadeType.MERGE,
                                                                        CascadeType.DETACH})
    private List<PFile> pFiles = new ArrayList<PFile>(20);

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to ReleaseType
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="RELEASE_TYPE_ID")
    private ReleaseType releaseType;

    public Release() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLifecycleStatus() {
        return this.lifecycleStatus;
    }

    public void setLifecycleStatus(String lifecycleStatus) {
        this.lifecycleStatus = lifecycleStatus;
    }

    public String getOperatingSystem() {
        return this.operatingSystem;
    }

    public void setOperatingSystem(String operatingSystem) {
        this.operatingSystem = operatingSystem;
    }

    public String getProtected_() {
        return this.protected_;
    }

    public void setProtected_(String protected_) {
        this.protected_ = protected_;
    }

    public Timestamp getReleaseDate() {
        return this.releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(Timestamp releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public String getReleaseName() {
        return this.releaseName;
    }

    public void setReleaseName(String releaseName) {
        this.releaseName = releaseName;
    }

    public String getShortDescription() {
        return this.shortDescription;
    }

    public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    }

    public List<PFile> getPFiles() {
        return this.pFiles;
    }

    public void setPFiles(List<PFile> pFiles) {
        this.pFiles = pFiles;
    }

    public ReleaseType getReleaseType() {
        return releaseType;
    }

    public void setReleaseType(ReleaseType releaseType) {
        this.releaseType = releaseType;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your criteria query written,

Comment: Your hibernate query does not has releasetyp3_.id. Please validate if you have pasted the right hibernate query here...

Comment: Thanks guys. I edited the post and added both hibernate query output and query formation line of code.

Comment: Using `group by` without aggregate functions is almost always a bad idea. What should the outcome of the select be anyway? Which record from each group do you expect?

Comment: Its a migration project , the same query is working fine with OpenJPA, DB2 and Websphere. Client wants to move it to Hibernate , Postgresql and JBoss. is this issue releated to "https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1615" ???

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you have received via Hibernate logs is clear enough, the issue is with your query that you have framed through Java. Did you try to execute the same query on `pgAdminIII`? If you run the standalone query, you would receive the same error.

The issue that you are facing is because of the columns that you have used in the `GROUP BY` clause are not available in the `SELECT` columns list. If you change your query to something like this, then you should be able to run the query without any issues, per se!

```
SELECT  r.release.protected_, 
        r.release.releaseType, 
        r.version  
FROM ReleaseCategory r 
WHERE   r.release.lifecycleStatus = :lifecycleStatus 
        AND r.release.releaseType IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY r.release.protected_, r.release.releaseType, r.version
```

You don't seem to use this query as mentioned in the question, but you've added two additional columns in the `GROUP BY` clause which are not present in the `SELECT` columns list.

Change is required in the `JAVA` code snippet that you've provided here in the question.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thansk N00b Pr0grammer.  I tried all the possible way to resolve the issue. The above query was tried earlier and getting the same exception. Basically the above one is the original query , later i added the two columns r.id, r.release.id based on the exception.

Comment: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "releasetyp3_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: @anandjava, Can you add just `r.release.id` to the Java code in the `GROUP BY` clause and try once?

Comment: After added the column in the Group By , getting the same exception.Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "releasetyp3_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 123

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. I changed the query like

> sqlString.append(" FROM ReleaseCategory r where
>   r.elease.lifecycleStatus = :lifecycleStatus "); sqlString.append(" and
>   r.release.releaseType is not null "); sqlString.append(" group by
>   r.release.protected_,r.release.releaseType.id, r.version.id , r.id 
>   ");

and its working fine.

Thanks for all..

Answer (score 0):

Your must join releaseType:

```
SELECT
  release.protected_, releaseType, r.version
FROM
  ReleaseCategory r 
JOIN
  r.release release
LEFT JOIN
  release.releaseType releaseType
WHERE
  release.lifecycleStatus = :lifecycleStatus
AND 
  releaseType IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  release.protected_, releaseType, r.version
```